# allow html tag into djimageslider slides title joomla 2.5

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, joomla2.5

What I'm trying to do is to add some HTML tags to my Djimageslider's slides titles in joomla 2.5. I will need something like this

```
something <b>more</b>
```

but when I click on save or apply then its remove all HTML tags.

I've check the administrator/com_content, which I think should be responsible for inserting the database data, but I couldn't find the answer there.

Can anyone help me with this headache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form inputs are "cleaned" by default and you want to tell Joomla not to touch its contents.

Find the component you are using in the url (option=com_djsomething?) I doubt it's com_content.

Once you have the component, you have to find where the form is defined.

The task in the url may help, also the view if it's there.  The form can be declared in one of two ways:

- by providing an xml manifest, which would be located in the component's folder /models/forms
- by inserting it in code, which could be in the component's folder /views/view_name (the default view name would be the component's name, but this can be overridden in the controller so look around).

In both cases, you should be able to find the line that corrensponds to your input, and specify **format="raw"** as a filter.

Check http://docs.joomla.org/Text_form_field_type  for syntax help of the xml manifest, or search the docs for the right JElement in code

The format parameter is optional, if it's not there just add it. Besides "raw" there are other filtering options available, make sure you do filter out undesired input and sanitize your inputs before saving to the db (use $db->quote() to insert field values in the query)